# Changing ownership of static directory not working in kubernetes

Tags: docker, magento, kubernetes, containers

I am trying to change ownership of static directory in a container but for some reason it's not working but it works on another directory.

```
securityContext:
  runAsUser: 0
command: ["/bin/sh"]
args:
- -c
- |
  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/pub/media
  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/pub/static
```

When I run `kubectl -n magento exec magento-web-dweq34672 -- ls -al var/www/html/pub` I see static directory still under root ownership. everytime I Am manually changing it using following which is getting frustrating now, any suggestions

`kubectl -n magento exec magento-web-dweq34672 -- chown -R www-data:www-data var/www/html/pub`

Comment: which directory are you changing permissions for ? what are its initial permission when the container is set up. Does the dockerfile mentions permission of any folders ?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested before you can use `initContainer` in your deployment spec.

Example:

```
initContainers:
        - name: my-init
          image: busybox:1.28
          command: [ 'sh', '-c', 'chown -R www-data:www-data var/www/html/pub']
```

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) you can find more information about initContainer

Another option is rebuild the image with the right permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Init container is what you need here, use init container to change the permissions and the ownership.